# Pass mongoose data into an angular 4 component 'detail' page?

Tags: javascript, angular, mongoose

I'm very new to angular 4 and mongoose and I'm not even positive I'm doing this correctly. I have a page where I list out schools. I'm able to add the schools to the database and when I click on one of the names (`school.name`) I have it go to a detail page. I have the route set up like `{ path: 'api/schools/:id',      component: SchoolDetailComponent }` in the html template on the  tag I have `routerLink="/api/schools/{{school._id}}"` which successfully loads the url http://localhost:3000/api/schools/592641e61e4e76cfda292b4a with the correct id number(obviously specific to any element.) What I'm not sure is how to load the info for that particular element into the detail page.

schools schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var schoolsSchema = new Schema({
  // _id
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  wave: { type: Number, default: 0 }, // of questions sent out
  questionCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }, // created
  phaseGate: {type: Number, default: 0},
  disabled: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});

// Export the Mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('School', schoolsSchema);
```

API:

```
    var router = require('express').Router();
    var School = require('../models/schools');
    var User = require('../models/users');
    var lock = require('./api-lock');

    // server routes thru /api/schools/ path
    // api/schools/ when calling from client

// SCHOOLS/ ROUTE >>>>>>>>>>>>
router.route('/')
    // GET REQUEST
    .get(lock.requireAdmin, (req, res) => {

        School
        .find({'disabled': { $in: [false, null]}}) // find all Schools
        .sort('-date')
        .exec((err, schools) => {
            if(err) {
                res.json(500, {msg: "error"});
            }
            res.json(schools);
        });
    })
    // POST REQUEST
    .post(lock.requireAdmin, (req, res) => {
        // create new school profile
        School.create(req.body, (err, school) => {
            if(err) {
              return res.json({msg: "error"});
            }
            res.json(school);
          });
    });


// SCHOOLS/WAVE/ ROUTE >>>>>>>>>>>>
router.route('/wave/update/')
    // PUT REQUEST
    // update wave count on school
    .put(lock.requireAdmin, (req, res) => {

        var schoolId = req.body._id;

        School
        .findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: schoolId }, // find indv School
            { $inc: { wave: 1}}, // replace name
            {new: true},
            (err, school) => {
                res.json(school);
            }
        )
    });


// SCHOOLS/:SCHOOL_ID ROUTE >>>>>>>>>>>>
router.route('/:id')
    // GET REQUEST
    .get(lock.requireSchoolAdmin, (req, res) => {
        School
        .findById({
            _id: req.params.school_id, // find indv School
      //disabled: { $in: [false, null]}
        })
        .select()
        .exec((err, school) => {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).send('School not found.')
            }
            res.json(school);
        });
    })
    // PUT REQUEST
    .put(lock.requireAdmin, (req, res) => {

        console.log(req);
        School
        .findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.params.school_id }, // find indv School
            { $set: { name: req.body.name }}, // replace name
            (err, school) => {
                res.json(school);
            }
        )
    })

// SCHOOLS/:SCHOOL_ID ROUTE >>>>>>>>>>>>
router.route('/phase/update/')
    // PUT REQUEST
    // Update school phaseGate
    .put(lock.requireAdmin, (req, res) => {

        console.log(req);
        School
        .findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.params.school_id }, // find indv School
            { $inc: {"phaseGate": 1 }}, // replace name
            (err, school) => {
                res.json(school);
            }
        )
    })


// SCHOOLS/COUNT/TOTAL/ ROUTE >>>>>>>>>>>>
router.route('/count/total/')
    // GET REQUEST
    .get(lock.requireAdmin, (req, res) => {
        School
        .count({}) // find School count total
        .exec((err, count) => {
            res.json(count);
        });
    });


module.exports = router;
```

School Detail Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from     '@angular/forms';
import {  ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { SchoolService } from '../services/school.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-school-detail',
  templateUrl: './school-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./school-detail.component.css']
})
export class SchoolDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  schools = [];
  school = {};

  admins = [];
  admin = {};

  constructor(private http: Http,
    private schoolService: SchoolService,
    private userService: UserService,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

          // route.snapshot.params['id'];
          // console.log('id');
         }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSchools();
    // this.getSchool();
    //
    console.log(this.school);
    });

    // this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    //     let schoolId = params['schoolId'];
    //     console.log(schoolId);
//   });

      // let SchoolId = this.route.snapshot.params["SchoolId"];
      // console.log(SchoolId);
  }

  //schools
  getSchools() {
    this.schoolService.getSchools().subscribe(
      data => this.schools = data,
      error => console.log(error),
      // () => this.isLoading = false
    );
  }

  // getSchool() {
  //   this.schoolService.getSchool().subscribe(
  //     data => this.school = data,
  //     error => console.log("getSchool" + error),
  //     // () => this.isLoading = false
  //
  //   );
  //   console.log(this.school)
  // }

  // getSchool(school) {
  //
  //     this.schoolService.getSchools(school).subscribe(
  //       res => {
  //         const pos = this.schools(school._id);
  //         // console.log(this.schools.map(elem => { return elem._id;     }).indexOf(school._id));
  //         console.log(school._id);
  //         // this.schools.splice(pos, 1);
  //
  //         // console.log(this.schools);
  //         // this.toast.setMessage('item deleted successfully.',     'success');
  //       },
  //       error => console.log(error)
  //     );
  // }
}
```

In the html i'm trying to call `school.name` in the html. commented out in the component code above, I've tried playing around with ActivatedRoute, but it doesn't seem to want to work. I've tried looking through google, stack overflow, github, youtube, and can't seem to get it to work. any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with  activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

```
public schoolname: string;

 constructor(private http: Http,private schoolService: SchoolService,private userService: UserService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
                this.schoolname=activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];       
             }

ngOnInit() {

console.log(this.schoolname)

 }
```

Comment: You're a genius, thank you! So would I next pass that through something like, ` getSchool(schoolname) { this.schoolService.getSchool().subscribe(data => this.school = data,)}` to get the rest of the info from the object? (not sure if thats the right syntax)

Comment: this.schoolService.getSchool().subscribe(data => {console.log(data) });